# Docker Cache BUNDLE INSTALL not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, docker

Anybody knows how to make BUNDLE INSTALL Cache'ing work in latest DOCKER release?
I've tried so far:

```
1. 
WORKDIR /tmp 
ADD ./Gemfile Gemfile
ADD ./Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

2.
ADD . opt/railsapp/
WORKIDR opt/rails/app
RUN bundle install
```

None of them work, it still runs "BUNDE INSTALL" everytime from scratch without Gemfile being changed.

Anyone knows how to make Caching for bundle install work correctly?

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 5):

Each time you change any file in your local app directory, the cache will be wiped out, forcing every step afterwards to be re-run, including the last `bundle install`.

The solution is don't run `bundle install` in step 2. You have already installed your gems in step 1 and there is little chance the Gemfile will change between step 1 and step 2 ;-).

The whole point of step 1 is to add your Gemfile, which should not change to often, so you can cache it and the subsequent bundle command before adding the rest of your app, which will probably change very often if you are still developing it.

Here's how the Dockerfile could look like:

```
1. 
WORKDIR /tmp 
ADD ./Gemfile Gemfile
ADD ./Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

2.
ADD . opt/railsapp/
WORKIDR opt/rails/app
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was looking for clarification after reading [this guide](https://blog.abevoelker.com/rails-development-using-docker-and-vagrant/) and finding a bit more visualization of the diffs in [this page](http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/docker/gotchas-in-writing-dockerfile-en/#build_caching_what_invalids_cache_and_not)

Comment: A more verbose version on this [blog post](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2014/01/06/how-to-skip-bundle-install-when-deploying-a-rails-app-to-docker/) is also nice

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Docker before 0.9.1 did not cache ADD instructions. Can you check that you're running a version of Docker 0.9.1 or greater?

Also, which installation of Docker are you using? According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5053), some users have experienced cache-busting ADD behavior when using unsupported Docker builds. Make sure you're using an official Docker build.

Comment: Thanks for link, i will take a look. I'm using latest LXC-DOCKER package for ubuntu 12.04, which is 0.12.0 , i know that there was bug with ADD permissions in 0.11.0 and i hoped it was fixed in 0.12 and i will be able to Cache bundle :

Answer (score 0):

ADD caching is based on all the metadata of the file, not just the contents.

if you are running `docker build` in a CI-like environment with a fresh checkout, then it is possible the timestamps of the files are being updated which would invalidate the cache.